# how to pass string into array as key and value

Tags: php, arrays, string

trying to pass string key and value into my array , here's the array

```
$array = array(
   'id' =>1,
   'name' => 'ahmed',
   'age' => 16,
   'country' => 'egypt',
   $string,
);
```

and my string var is

```
$string = "  'city'=>'cairo'  ";
```

when using the code in that way doesn't works so is there anyway to inserting string in a array as key and value

Comment: $arrayname[indexname] = $value; try using this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
$array = array(
       'id' =>1,
       'name' => 'ahmed',
       'age' => 16,
       'country' => 'egypt',
    );
         $array['city'] = 'cairo';
         print_r( $array);
```

it will output

> Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => ahmed [age] => 16 [country] => egypt [city] => cairo )